# Warning encountered using ideal translational velocity and not ideal force source in Simscape for spring-mass-damper system

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

For my project, I am planning to conduct simulations in Simulink for an investigation on viscoelasticity behaviour that 3D printed plastic coupons seem to exhibit. Viscoelastic behaviour can be represented by different spring-dashpot combinations such as the ones seen in the Maxwell or Kevin-Voigt models.

For this purpose, I will be using Simscape elements to represent the layers of the 3D-printed object using spring, mass and dampers in the system. For my first attempt, I have used just a simple two mass system with spring-dashpot in series and observe their displacement using the scope element. For the the mechanical source, I have tried using both an ideal translational velocity source as well as an ideal force source.
Here is my Simulink diagram:

[image: Simulink Diagram with ideal translational velocity source]

Initially, I tried using an ideal translational velocity source, I encountered two warnings:

[image: Simulink warning box]

Thus, I attempted to use an ideal force source instead as most of the examples for modelling in spring-mass-damper using Simscape that I found used that as a mechanical source instead, which managed to work. (I only changed the source from an ideal translational velocity to an ideal force source)

[image: Simulink diagram with ideal force source]

However for the purpose of my experiment, it would serve me better to use the ideal translational velocity source instead as the strain testing was conducted at a constant speed of 10mm/s that is to say a constant velocity rather than a constant force which would imply that the speed is changing.

I am not sure whether the warnings obtained when using the ideal translational velocity element would affect my results and how I can deal with the warnings, would really appreciate any help I can get as I am super new to Simulink! :)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code properly as text (not as a link to an image)

Comment: @JonScott Simulink is a graphical block diagram environment on top of MATLAB, there is no code to include...

Comment: thanks for helping embed the image! @am304